# определить вид числа без условных операторов и циклов

Tags: python

Задача:
Дано целое число n. Выведите следующее за ним четное число.
Задачу необходимо решить целочисленными операциями без использования условных операторов и\или циклов.
ввод: 5, вывод: 6; ввод: 6, вывод: 8

Comment: Задаче тебе, тебе и выполнять.

Comment: @Эникейщик, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Выведите следующее за ним четное число

подсказка 1: если разделить целочисленно целое число на 2, а потом умножить на 2, то получиться... чётное число не больше изначального

дальше думайте сами

подсказка 2.1:  если сбросить самый правый бит натуральному числу, то получится чётное число не больше изначального

подсказка 2.2: числа в битовом представлении легко записывать через `0b<битовое представление>`, например `0xb1110111`

дальше думайте сами

подсказка 3: условия можно записывать неявно, преобразовывая булев тип в целочисленный, например int(False) = 0, а int(True) = 1, а полученные 0/1 очень хорошо умножаются на любые натуральные числа :)

дальше думайте сами

В общем ваша задача решается минимум 3 способами + их вариациями (т.е. решений 5-10 сделать можно разной степени извращённости)

Comment: спасибо, примерно думал возле 1 варианта, но никак не доходило

Comment: @asixwert, все варианты крутятся около сложения, а вот сделать вариант без сложения - вот это было бы интересно

Comment: @asixwert, что-то не подумал сразу - деление по модулю - это 4 способ, который я как-то посчитал эквивалентным способу 3) - так что есть и такой вариант, хотя он и отличается :)